# SetParameter is failing for few android device

Tags: android, android-camera

I have built a android camera app, which works fine for few devices and in some devices it crashes before starting the preview. Tried with all stackOverflow solution, but nothing worked for me.

My Preview Class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    protected List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPictureSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    private Camera.Size mPictureSize;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CameraPreview(Activity activity, Camera camera) {
        super(activity);
        mCamera = camera;
        setCamera(mCamera);
        mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
        SurfaceHolder mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {

        mCamera = camera;
         if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(getDisplayOrientation());
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mSupportedPictureSizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            requestLayout();
            parameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
            parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
            int index = parameters.getExposureCompensation();
            parameters.setExposureCompensation(index);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        }
    }


    public int getDisplayOrientation() {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT, info);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        int degree = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degree = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degree = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degree = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degree = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degree) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;
        } else {
            result = (info.orientation - degree + 360) % 360;
        }
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview in surfaceCreated: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
        if(mSupportedPictureSizes != null){
            mPictureSize = getOptimalPictureSize();
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.01;
        double targetRatio = (double) height / width;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = height;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
```

// Here it is returning optimal preview size.
For Example : Moto G has 720*1280 screen resolution, it works perfectly fine for by returning optimalSize as 720*1280.

But for Moto X which has same resolution 720*1280 it crashes before starting the preview. It is return width = 640, height=480 which is incorrect.

```
            Log.d("getOptimalPreviewSize",
                    String.format(
                            "getOptimalPreviewSize result: width = %d, height = %d for input width = %d, height = %d",
                            optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height, width,
                            height));
        return optimalSize;
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPictureSize() {
        if (mCamera == null) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Camera.Size> cameraSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size optimalSize = mCamera.new Size(0, 0);
        double previewRatio = (double) mPreviewSize.width / mPreviewSize.height;
        for (Camera.Size size : cameraSizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - previewRatio) > 0.01f)
                continue;
            if (size.height > optimalSize.height) {
                optimalSize = size;
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize.height == 0) {
            for (Camera.Size size : cameraSizes) {
                if (size.height > optimalSize.height) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        if (mCamera != null) {

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
             Camera.Size mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
           parameters.setPictureSize(mPictureSize.width, mPictureSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("SurfaceDestroyed", " Error handling surface destroy method");
        }
    }
}
```